# how Store result of a command in an array and put "none" i the information is missing?

Tags: arrays, bash, tabs

Im using a function that gives me 300 000 lines that look like this :

```
XXXXXXXXX 
WWWWWWWWWWWW

ZZZZZZZZZZ

eeeeeeeeeee
```

and i want to get something like this in an array

```
tab[0]=XXXXXXXXX tab[1]= tab[1]= WWWWWWWWWWWW tab[1]= none
```

I tried this :

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in text.txt
do
   tab=[i]
done
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Could you please also format your example data as it were code? Otherwise symbols could be misplaced or misinterpreted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: Why do you have 3 different values for `tab[1]`? Did you mean `tab[2]` and `tab[3]`?

Comment: I don't see how your desired result is related to the sample file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while read` loop to read the file line by line, and append the line to the `tab` array.

```
tab=()
while read -r line; do
    tab+=("${line:-none}")
done < filename
```

`:-default` in a variable expansion means to use `default` if the variable is empty, so empty lines will be replaced with `none` in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mapfile` to map lines of text to an array:

```bash
mapfile -t tab < text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ readarray -t tab <file
$ declare -p tab
declare -a tab=([0]="XXXXXXXXX " [1]="WWWWWWWWWWWW" [2]="" [3]="ZZZZZZZZZZ" [4]="" [5]="eeeeeeeeeee")

# adding none
$ readarray -t tab < <(awk '{print ($0=="" ? "none" : $0)}' file)
$ declare -p tab
declare -a tab=([0]="XXXXXXXXX" [1]="WWWWWWWWWWWW" [2]="none" [3]="ZZZZZZZZZZ" [4]="none" [5]="eeeeeeeeeee")

# associative array
$ declare -A arr="($(awk '{print ($0=="" ? "[tab,"NR"]=\"none\"" : "[tab,"NR"]=\""$0"\"")}' file))"
$ declare -p arr
declare -A arr=([tab,6]="eeeeeeeeeee" [tab,4]="ZZZZZZZZZZ" [tab,5]="none" [tab,2]="WWWWWWWWWWWW" [tab,3]="none" [tab,1]="XXXXXXXXX" )
```